# Saving data after editing primefaces datatable to database in integration of hibernate spring jsf and primefaces

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i want to edit a row in primfaces datatable. i am using integration of jsf hibernate spring primefaces. but i have following error.

```
javax.el.ELException: /personel.xhtml @60,83 listener="#{personelMB.updatePersonel(personel.personel_id)}": org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

personelmanagedbean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="personelMB")
@ViewScoped
public class PersonelBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{PersonelService}")
    IPersonelService personelservice;
    List<Personel> personelList;

    private int personel_id;
    private String pname;
    private String pfamily;
    private String paddress;
    private String pphone;
//getter and setter
public void updatePersonel(int personel_id){
        Personel personel=(Personel)personelservice.getPersonelId(personel_id);
        getPersonelservice().updatePersonel(personel);
    }

}
```

personel.xhtml:

```
<h:form  prependId="false">  

    <p:dataTable id="pdataTable" var="personel" value="#{personelMB.personelList}" rowKey="#{personelMB.personel_id}" editable="true"
    >  
  <p:ajax event="rowEdit" update="@this" listener="#{personelMB.updatePersonel(personel.personel_id)}"/>
        <f:facet name="header">  
            اطلاعات پرسنل 
        </f:facet>  

        <p:column> 

            <f:facet name="header">  
               شماره پرسنلی  
            </f:facet>  

            <h:outputText value="#{personel.personel_id}" />  

            <f:facet name="footer">  
                کدملی 
            </f:facet>  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام">
        <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">  
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pname}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
              <h:inputText value="#{personel.pname}" />
              </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor> 
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="نام خانوادگی"> 
         <p:cellEditor> 
         <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pfamily}" /> 
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{personel.pfamily}" />
            </f:facet> 
            </p:cellEditor>  
        </p:column>  

        <p:column headerText="آدرس"> 
         <p:cellEditor> 
         <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.paddress}" />  
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{personel.paddress}" />
            </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor> 
        </p:column>  
   <p:column headerText="تلفن"> 
   <p:cellEditor> 
   <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{personel.pphone}" />
            </f:facet> 
            <f:facet name="input">
            <h:inputText value="#{personel.pphone}" /> 
            </f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

   <p:column headerText="ويرايش">

         <p:rowEditor /> 



   </p:column>
        <f:facet name="footer">  
            تعداد رکورد#{fn:length(personelMB.getPersonelList())} میباشد.  
        </f:facet>  

    </p:dataTable>  

</h:form>
```

personelservice:

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public class PersonelService implements IPersonelService{
    IPersonelDao personeldao;
//getter and setter
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
    @Override
    public void updatePersonel(Personel personel) {
        getPersoneldao().updatePersonel(personel);

    }
```

personeldao:

```
public class PersonelDao implements IPersonelDao {
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
//getter and setter
@Override
public void updatePersonel(Personel personel) {
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(personel);

}
```

please help me how to edit my data table and save it in database.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of fetching a Hibernate entity in one Transaction and attempting to update it in another Transaction with a different Hibernate session.

To do this properly you need to fetch and then update your `Personel` object in the same Transaction.  This means that you need to have one `@Transactional` business logic method that you call from your ManagedBean that does both.

In IPersonelService implementation class:

```
@Transactional
public void updatePersonel(int personel_id, String pname, String pfamily ...){
    Personel personel = personelDao.getPersonel(personel_id);
    personel.setPName(pname);
    ....
    getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(personel); 
}
```

This will seperate, your business logic from your presentation logic as well as make all of your database calls behind a single Transaction.